# Instance Variables Not Updating

Tags: c++, video

When I run my little game, battle commences but after every turn, the players attack but health doesn't go down (i.e. the game never ends and it keeps printing the same health over and over). I know it has something to do with the inflictDamage system. Can anyone see my error?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class Hulk
{
private:
    string playerName;
    string color;
    double weight; //In kilograms
    double height; //In centimeters
    double health;
    int strength;
    int speed;
    vector<char> moveSet;
public:
    Hulk(const string& playerName, string color):
        playerName(playerName), color(color) {
            this->weight = 500.0;
            this->height = 200.0;
            this->health = 110.0;
            this->strength = 200;
            this->speed = 50;
            moveSet.push_back('P');
            moveSet.push_back('K');
            moveSet.push_back('S');
            if(playerName == " ")
            {
                cout << "Not a valid name!" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
    }
    string getPlayerName()
    {
        return this->playerName;
    }
    double getWeight()
    {
        return this->weight;
    }
    double getHeight()
    {
        return this->height;
    }
    double getHealth()
    {
        return this->health;
    }
    void setHealth(double x)
    {
        this->health = x;
    }
    void takeDamage(double x)
    {
        this->health -= x;
    }
    void inflictDamage(double x, Hulk enemy)
    {
        enemy.takeDamage(x);
    }
    void smash(Hulk x)
    {
        this->inflictDamage(50.0, x);
    }
    void punch(Hulk x)
    {
        this->inflictDamage(25.0, x);
    }
    void kick(Hulk x)
    {
        this->inflictDamage(30.0, x);
    }
    vector<char> getMoveSet()
    {
        return this->moveSet;
    }
};
int main()
{
    /** Creates a random number. */
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));

    cout << "This is a hulk battle test." << endl;
    vector<string> names(3);
    names[0] = "Randy";
    names[1] = "Chris";
    names[2] = "Carlos";
    cout << "Please enter a name: ";
    string playerName;
    cin >> playerName;
    Hulk player(playerName, "green");
    int r = rand() % 3;
    Hulk enemy(names[r], "green");
    cout << player.getPlayerName() << " vs. " << enemy.getPlayerName() << "!" << endl;
    bool gameOver = false;
    while(gameOver == false)
    {
        char playerTurn;
        bool playerMove = false;
        while(playerMove == false)
        {
            cout << "Your turn, what will you do? ((P)unch, (K)ick, (S)mash): ";
            cin >> playerTurn;
            if(playerTurn == 'P')
            {
                player.punch(enemy);
                playerMove = true;
            }
            else if(playerTurn == 'K')
            {
                player.kick(enemy);
                playerMove = true;
            }
            else if(playerTurn == 'S')
            {
                player.smash(enemy);
                playerMove = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "This is not a valid move. Please try again." << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        if(enemy.getHealth() <= 0.0)
        {
            cout << "You have defeated " << enemy.getPlayerName() << ". Game over!" << endl;
            gameOver = true;
        }
        char enemyTurn;
        bool enemyMove = false;
        while(enemyMove == false)
        {
            vector<char> enemyMoves = enemy.getMoveSet();
            int moveNumber = rand() % 3;
            char move = enemyMoves[moveNumber];
            if(move == 'P')
            {
                enemy.punch(player);
                cout << "You have been punched and lost 25 health. You are now at " << player.getHealth() << " health." << endl;
                enemyMove = true;
            }
            else if(move == 'K')
            {
                enemy.kick(player);
                cout << "You have been kicked and lost 30 health. You are now at " << player.getHealth() << " health." << endl;
                enemyMove = true;
            }
            else if(move == 'S')
            {
                enemy.smash(player);
                cout << "You have been smashed and lost 50 health. You are now at " << player.getHealth() << " health." << endl;
                enemyMove = true;
            }
        }
        if(player.getHealth() <= 0.0)
        {
            cout << enemy.getPlayerName() << " has defeated you! Game over!" << endl;
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A method like

```
void inflictDamage(double x, Hulk enemy)
{
    enemy.takeDamage(x);
}
```

cannot change the object `enemy`, since that object is passed "by value", which means, every time you call `inflictDamage(x,e)`, there will be created a copy of `e`, and `takeDamage` will be applied to this copy, not to the original `e`.

What you probably want is

```
void inflictDamage(double x, Hulk &enemy)
{
    enemy.takeDamage(x);
}
```

which makes `enemy` to be passed "by reference".